# Why some NPM script argument syntax in echo message work and others don't?

Tags: npm, arguments, npm-scripts

I wanted to use a dynamic message print call to trim NPM scripts, but stumbled on some curious differences.

My package.json looks like following:

```
"scripts": {
    "foo": "echo \"\033[0;31m****\n This is foo message \n****\" && npm run test",
    "bar": "echo \"\033[0;31m****\n This is bar message \n****\" && npm run compile",
    "baz": "echo \"\033[0;31m****\n This is baz message \n****\" && npm run dev"
}
```

To avoid repetition and shorten the scripts I implemented new script with `$npm_config_argument` to make package.json scripts as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "echomsg": "echo \"\033[0;31m****\n This is $npm_config_msg message \n****\",
    "foo": "npm run echomsg --msg=foo && npm run test",
    "bar": ...
}
```

as per [this article](https://dev.to/felipperegazio/handling-command-line-arguments-in-npm-scripts-2ean).

Now I should be able to call `npm run foo`,
but this didn't work. Instead, it prints

```
> echo "\033[0;31m****************
 This is $npm_config_msg message
****************" "silent" "foo"

****************
 This is  message
**************** silent foo
```

I found out that the issue was with `$npm_config_<ARGUMENT>`, because with

```
    "echomsg": "echo \"\033[0;31m****\n This is $npm_config_messag message \n****\",
    "foo": "npm run echomsg --messag=foo && npm run test",
```

I get

```
> echo "\033[0;31m****************
 This is $npm_config_messag message
****************"

****************
 This is  message
****************
```

and with

```
    "echomsg": "echo \"\033[0;31m****\n This is $npm_config_message message \n****\",
    "foo": "npm run echomsg --message=foo && npm run test",
```

or with

```
    "echomsg": "echo \"\033[0;31m****\n This is $npm_config_myvar message \n****\",
    "foo": "npm run echomsg --myvar=foo && npm run test",
```

I finally get what I wanted:

```
> echo "\033[0;31m****************
 This is $npm_config_message/myvar message
****************"

****************
 This is foo message
****************
```

So the question is:
**Why this happens?**
What's with the argument syntax that does not accept "msg" or "messag" but some other strings are fine?